# How can I record (rosbag) the appropiate nodes for simulatting gmmaping?

Tags: navigation, rosbag, turtlebot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have had some trouble with gmmaping with turtlebot. What happens is that when I try to make big maps (a whole building of my university) it seems like it divides the map in different sections and, sometimes it moves the sections so the map at the end fits the reality but only by sections.

For example there are 4 main corridors that make a perfect cross. If I start at the very beginning of one corridor at the end I'll have 4 corridors but not necessarily in a 90º each corner.

In order to work in the code I want to record with rosbag the topics that will allow me to simulate that I'm driving the robot. Which ones do you think I should record? I tried with odom, scan and tf and it doesn't work well, although I can see in rviz the scan the robot doesn't move.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12254/how-can-i-record-(rosbag)-the-appropiate-nodes-for-simulatting-gmmaping?/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gmapping itself only needs the `/scan` and `/tf` topics. `/odom` could also be useful. Gmapping doesn't care about much else. It just needs to know the transforms for base_link->odom and your_laser_scan_frame->base_link. As long as these are being published, gmapping should have no problem. What problems do you encounter when using just these three topics?

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0